# HTMLunit - Facebook Login

Tags: java, htmlunit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
    webClient.setJavaScriptEngine(new JavaScriptEngine(webClient));
    HtmlPage page1 = null;
    try {
        page1 = webClient.getPage("http://www.facebook.com");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    final HtmlForm form = (HtmlForm) page1.getElementById("login_form");

    final HtmlSubmitInput button = (HtmlSubmitInput) form.getInputsByValue("Log In").get(0);
    final HtmlTextInput textField = (HtmlTextInput) page1.getElementById("email");
    textField.setValueAttribute("test@test.com");
    final HtmlPasswordInput textField2 = (HtmlPasswordInput) page1.getElementById("pass");
    textField2.setValueAttribute("password1");
    try {
        HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
        System.out.println(page2.getTitleText());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm trying to use the HTMLUnit to log into an account on facebook. However I'm getting this error:

I'm looking to create a program that automates some of the things that I do with my pages that I have on facebook. I know something like this probably already exists but I'm making it for fun.

```
======= EXCEPTION START ========


EcmaError: lineNumber=[97] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y8/r/ElsISGBmlSN.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function addImport in object [object CSSStyleSheet]. (https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y8/r/ElsISGBmlSN.js#97)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function addImport in object [object CSSStyleSheet]. (https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/y8/r/ElsISGBmlSN.js#97)
```

Comment: There is no exception with my credentials with latest snapshot, which you can get from https://ci.canoo.com/teamcity/viewLog.html?buildTypeId=HtmlUnit_FastBuild&buildId=lastSuccessful&tab=artifacts

Comment: Can you show me your logs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I stopped getting this error when I added a BrowserVersion into the WebClient constructor:

```
 final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
```

Comment: I have tried this but could not get logged into facebook. Can you please check my question [Cannot login programmatically to facebook using htmlunit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34044808/cannot-login-programmatically-to-facebook-using-htmlunit)

Comment: This was a while back. Facebook are having a lot of problems with bots at the moment so I think they might have upped the security. I'll have a look at your question when I can however and see if your code is any different to mine :)

Comment: Thank you koplocal. I hope we can find a solution.

Comment: I can't comment cause I don't have enough reputation on your question. Have you made sure that you logged out of facebook before running this?

Comment: Hi, koplocal! First of all I would like to thank you very much for taking the time to invastigate the problem. Yes, I have made sure that I am logged out of facebook before running the application. Still nothing :( Can you please check if the code is still working in your case? Cheers!